# How to know any file/program is associated with which default program by Java?

Tags: java

I just wantto know how can I know the default program associated with any external program/file. For ex-by default, a java file opens with which program? This I have to know using a Java program itself.

Comment: *"I just want .. know the default program"*  What business is it of yours what app. I (as a potential end user) has as the default for a Word doc, or FLV, or.. anything.  If you intend to open a `File` in the default app., look to [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) it will report failure with exceptions - if successful, it will **not** reveal the app. used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On **windows**:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("ftype > %YOUR_DIRECTORY%\\type_program.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("%YOUR_DIRECTORY%\\type_program.properties");
prop.load(in);
```

on **Unix\Linux**:

you can use `file` command for specific extension and get the corresponding mapping.

at this point you got all the mappings in your properties object.
enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a file with the associated program, you don't really need to know the associated program since Java can do the association for you using the java.awt.Desktop class.

```
// application associated to a file extension
public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(document);
}
```